# python import file at same folder

Tags: python, import, python-import

I am trying to import another `.py` file in the same folder, but fails. I can't figure out why.

folder `A` contains folder `B`, file `c.py` and `d.py` is in folder `B`, I am trying to `import c` to `d`, and there is a `\__init__.py` file in folder, I also tried something like write `\__all__ = ['c']` in file `\__init__.py` because `import c` was not working

Comment: what is the exception or error that you are getting??

Comment: could you explain more clearly what you want..?

Answer (score 0):

it should work with import and filename(without .py)

```
import c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like;
`from c import *`

Answer (score 0):

Try a relative import like this:

```
from . import c
```

Or something like

```
from .c import XYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit unsure about the exact structure you have. So below is a bash-script that generates the structure I think you described and various ways to import and reference the things in the files.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -fr A
mkdir A
mkdir A/B
echo "cx = 34" > A/B/c.py
echo "dx = 22" > A/B/d.py
touch A/B/__init__.py

cd A
python -c "import B"
python -c "import B.c"
python -c "import B.c; print B.c.cx"
python -c "from B import d; print d.dx"

cd B
python -c "import c; print c.cx"
```

The expected output will be from cx, dx and cx again. So:

```
34
22
34
```